# PHP script for sending push notification using curl

Tags: php, api, curl, push-notification

Looking for a php script that can send push notification to firefox browser.

Currently i am using terminal command for sending.

```
curl -H "TTL: 60" -X POST https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/wpush/v1/gAAAAABZ5aXkyhc1hAlytfvKWAUJ6a9dBuMeGPc1z88ZxvDxJvM2dSRDBWj30puanYg65dANmncdpulM1U7M6zWfiKtr-lO1pr5b0AmIU-MRDgDlmciFATY4rc59EPvgoyO1_TsJmg8l
```

Second:
Is there endpoint is enough to send push notifications ?

Comment: You really can't Google this or something? Here's an example: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php

Comment: @Frank, I tried this but now this error is at javascript push event. And its only limited for firefox.
Now, Can i implement firebase web push notifications for all chrome and firefox browser?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$ch=curl_init("https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/wpush/v1/gAAAAABZ5aXkyhc1hAlytfvKWAUJ6a9dBuMeGPc1z88ZxvDxJvM2dSRDBWj30puanYg65dANmncdpulM1U7M6zWfiKtr-lO1pr5b0AmIU-MRDgDlmciFATY4rc59EPvgoyO1_TsJmg8l");
curl_setopt_array($ch,array(
        CURLOPT_POST=>1,
        CURULOPT_VERIFYPEER=>0,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST=>0,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=>array(
                'TTL: 60'
        )
));
curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Great :) Its working but now i am able to send web push notification with payload 
{"endpoint":"https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send/foQCTeKZNH4:APA91bGltRAetQCkxs3U6wndrmLJ9ReQ7PTCSG2RguQn7oM8oB4cxWSzTuG5tZ01HrWv6dnF9w2hlDU8O0FVVY_9dBD0OQMqaTc2j1xyEjVh8HrgDIPJmxTTLP1_1EAAQMKpupLQml-e","expirationTime":null,"keys":{"p256dh":"BIIwQ2FB6NtKssv6HL601EkynLQk35vihdxMiiRmzR_aRmeQXS7ImR3iKRfMVM9WydCLvMDo4hVSkUQyRsRW42g=","auth":"y82QT1WmQoxxH-aK0bqShw=="}}

Comment: @rescue uhh, good for you? Is that a question?